# how to count all pairs such that w^x=y^z, where 1<=w,x,y,x<=n and 1<=n<=1000000

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, number-theory, counting

how to count all pairs such that w^x=y^z, where 1<=w,x,y,x<=n and 1<=n<=1000000
for example for n=3, there is 15 solutions

1^1=1^1

1^1=1^2

1^1=1^3

1^2=1^1

1^2=1^2

1^2=1^3

1^3=1^1

1^3=1^2

1^3=1^3

2^1=2^1

2^2=2^2

2^3=2^3

3^1=3^1

3^2=3^2

3^3=3^3

Comment: `w,x,y,x` w,x,y,**z**

Comment: Hint: prime factorization.

Answer (score 0):

Count how many pairs have a product of 1; there are $n^2$ = $10^{12}$. It’s all the cases $1^x = 1^z$. Then ignore w, y = 1.

Count the cases with identical left and right side $w^x = w^x$. There are $(n-1) \cdot n$ cases.

Divide the numbers from 2 to n into (here) about 999,000 non-powers, about 1000 squares, 100 cubes etc. Each number goes into one category only, so 64 counts as a sixth power. Now you count separately all cases of (i-th power)^x = (j-th power)^z with i ≠ j.

Two such numbers can only be equal if they are equal to say $(t^i)^x = (t^j)^z$ for some non-power t, and x, z are both multiples of gcd(i, j) so the total exponents are the same. Say i is smaller. Then the different values $t^j <= n$ are one limitation, and there are fewer possible exponents for $t^i$.

For example if i = 3, j = 7, then $t^3$ raised to the power 7, 14, 21 etc matches $t^7$ raised to the power 3, 6, 9, 12 etc. There are 142,857 multiples of 7 up to a million, so we have 142,857 pairs for each of the very small set of possible t (only t = 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 have 7th powers up to n = 1,000,000).

i = 1, j = 2: There are less than 1000 squares $t^2 ≤ n$. There are 500,000 possible exponents, for example 2 or 24 raised to the power 2, 4, 6, 8 etc equals 4 or $24^2$ raised to the power 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

Easiest to count the cases for i < j, then double the number for the cases i > j.